# Unix Program Using command line arguments check whether the given file exists in the given directory or not....?

Tags: file, unix, directory, command, arguments

I need a command line arguments program in unix which takes a source file name and  directory name as command line argument and print a message 'Yes' , if the file is found in the given directory.....

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried? Please mention in your question.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -e $1 ]
then
   echo 'Yes'
fi
```

Of course you could make it much better by handling more than one file, or by returning 'No' if the file doesn't exist.